# What is this old Anime set in prehistoric times?

Tags: ryu-the-primitive-boy

I watched it as a kid in the early 90's but the style was a bit older. It was on VHS.

The title was something like: Ray/Rei the hero? of the jungle? but it was a dubbed version so I'm not sure.
The protagonist is Ray? a young man. He has black hair and wears yellow furs. I don't remember the plot but he travels with his friends in a prehistoric world.

I remember two scenes:

Somewhere in the middle of the movie - they are on a raft on a lake and under them is a ginormous dinosaur. I guess it emerges from the water causing them to ride the wave and scream.

Towards the very end - there is a village where a volcano is about to erupt so they want to sacrifice a girl to it: that would be the friend of the protagonist and the granddaughter of the old woman who wants to sacrifice her.

Beware Spoilers!

> Volcano erupts, girl gets killed somehow I think in a fight, someone lays the girl down on the ground with the volcano with flowing lava in the background, old woman is praying to the volcano. And my friend's mom turned off the TV saying "you shouldn't watch films like this" (well, too late) and I never knew the end.

The old woman had long white hair & purple robes?, girl had long brown hair.

Please tell me what this is, I cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is [Ryu the Primitive Boy](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1463)

[image: Screenshot from ANN - original URL]

Plot summary from ANN:

> Set in primitive times, a baby with white skin is born into the world. As his skin color is different from the rest of the children around him, the baby is immediately disliked and alienated from the others. Deserted and left on his own, the baby is eventually picked up by an ape called Kitty and raised as her child. The baby, Ryuu, grows up to be a good man but at this moment, his mother is attacked and killed by Tirano. In order to defeat Tirano and also find his real mother, Ryuu decides to set off on his own journey. In the midst of his travels, he meets the siblings Ran and Don. With his new-found companions, Ryuu begins his battle against hardships and obstacles.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Whether right or wrong, do you have anything to support your answer?  This is currently a link only answer which is not condusive to the Stack Exchange system in case the link becomes inactive.

Comment: Yes, it is this one. Thank you very very much!