# An old anime/cartoon set in prehistoric time where the main character dresses like Tarzan and lives in a jungle

Tags: identification-request

I am looking for an old anime/cartoon. I have no idea about the name, the year it was published, the original language or whether or not it was an actual anime.

Things I know:

- It takes place in prehistoric times, a little bit after dinosaurs.
- It was an adult man (dressed like Tarzan) that was struggling to survive (I think he had blond hair, and possible a girlfriend or wife).
- He was living in the jungle with thick vegetation.
- I watched it in 2000 ± 2 years but the anime could be 20 years older than that.

I think the main character's name was Koblan(k)/Coblan(k)/Moblan(k). His name was also mentioned in the intro.

It was played in Greece. It's not [*Shounen Kenya*](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=2279) or [*Genshi Shounen Ryuu*](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=1686).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Details such as when or what year you watched it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the plot?

Comment: I watched it at 2000 +/- 2 years but it could be 20 years older than that.

Comment: Could be the same as this one? http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11371/what-is-this-old-anime-set-in-prehistoric-times

Comment: No, it's not Genshi Shounen Ryuu.

Comment: Thank you guys, this was my favorite show when i was young, i'm so happy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not Japanese animation.

Answer (score 6):

Isn't it [**Rahan**](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rahan)? I know it's a pretty old french comic, even [the animation adaptation](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rahan,_fils_des_%C3%A2ges_farouches) made out of it is quite old (1986).

It's a blond guy with a loin cloth, the action is set in prehistoric times.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much... That's what i was looking for. I wish you the best.

Comment: if it's right, you can 'accept' it by clicking the tick underneath his answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably [Future Boy Conan](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/future-boy-conan). It's pretty old, with its first airing in 1978. It was fairly popular, so I wouldn't be surprised to find that it had been translated into several languages.

[image]

Obviously, his name is Conan, but the wife you are thinking of might be Lana, a girl he rescues who is a significant character in the show.

[image]

As the name suggests, it's a time travel show, so many eras are mashed together and at several points Conan swings out of trees like Tarzan and encounters primitive people.

Plot Synopsis:

> In AD 2008, mankind developed deadly weapons and eradicated most of the Earth and its people. 20 years later, a young boy named Conan and his 'grandpa', one of the last survivors of the devastation, live a peaceful life on Remnant Island. One day Conan rescues a girl on the beach named Lana and learns the true nature of the rest of the world. After Lana is kidnapped, Conan's good nature propels him into the biggest adventure of his life: to find Lana, High Harbor, Dr. Lao, and a way to crush the evil and oppressive city of Industria.

Comment: Sorry but it's not this one. The character to the one i am talking was adult. Thnx anyway